# Setting intent putExtra value using a method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, methods

I'm new to Android programming and I'm having a small problem that's probably very easy to fix. I'm making a very basic game,and when the game is finished I want to return the high score back to the main menu.I'm generally okay with how intents work but I'm having a little difficulty with this one;I want to extract the score (hitCount) value from one class and use it in a putExtra in another class.

So, this code is in GameActivity:

```
public void finish(){
      Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
      super.finish();
    }
```

And this code is in GameView:

```
public int getHitCount(){
return hitCount;
}
```

I'm sure it's probably a very simple problem with the second code,but I'm getting no errors in Eclipse; it simply crashes the application in my AVD when I return to the game's main menu.

If it helps,this is the code I'm using on my main menu;

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (returnIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                int scoreFromGame = returnIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

And this is the error I'm getting in my logcat:

```
04-18 04:51:33.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {cct.mad.lab/cct.mad.lab.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you shouldn't call super.finish() in your GameActivity.

Comment: @serious198706: That seems to just make the back button on my AVD do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is gameView.getHitCount() in the first snippet of code, try to check if it's really a number or it's null

Answer (score 0):

Onactivityresult work when it knows which intent is called and therefore the same intent will.send the result.here you are creating intent in main activity but it doesn't expect any intent result because it does not called any intent thats why its throw runtime exception.i would advice you to use shared preference for this, as it is easy to implement and suitable for your game.